# require.js dependency analysis tool

Tags: javascript, dependencies, requirejs

How to detect circular dependencies from a project built using requir.js?

For instance

```
/* File: MyView.js */
define(['backbone','views/myview','object_x'], function(BB,V,X){
   ...
});

/* File: Object_X.js */
define(['backbone','jquery','views/myview','object_x'], function(BB,$,V,X){
   ...
});
```

what I mean is that as the project gets bigger, manually inspecting each file becomes a hassle.

*Edit:*
How about detecting redundant dependencies?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I Googled your title word-for-word, and this was the first result...

https://npmjs.org/package/madge

Comment: This SO post appeared below that link in my Google search and I still trusted going here first. Now I feel silly.

Comment: I googled his title word for word, and this SO page was the first result.

Answer (score 3):

Use [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js) to optimize the code. During build process it will list files that were included while building.

If you want to do more dependency graph analysis the semi-private [onResourceLoad API](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Internal-API%3a-onResourceLoad) may be helpful.